How to create multiple actions (animations) from modifiers and export them with the model?
I'm trying to make a Slime monster with a wave modifier animation for idle and one for wobbling motion when moving forward.
So I have two questions:

How to bake a modifier animation into a fbx file?
How to have two modifier animations as actions into a single fbx?

Is that possible?
Thanks
